# Is there any prerequisite for a web page to be integrated into an iFrame?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, embedding

I am currently working on a user interface that can integrate other pages in the form of `<iframe>`s into the canvas of the page or in a new window, using JavaScript to control that `<iframe>`.

While trying to integrate several partner applications in said frame, I've realized that some pages work fine, though others do not support being integrated (showing a browser error message saying so) -- I know there are ways to prevent the embedding of your page (the `X-Frame-Options`meta tag or `FrameKiller` JavaScript).

---

What I'd like to know is if there are prerequisites for a page to be embedded into an `<iframe>`, even without the developers of those partner applications actively preventing the embedding of their pages. I couldn't seem to find any kind of standard compatability matrix in my searches, all I *can* seem to find are the prevention methods.

Do you have any advice on this?